# Multimonitor in login screen vs. lock screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, login-screen, lock-screen, dualhead

I have a multiple monitor setup with two screens. The login screen uses dual monitor mode (as seen on the first picture), but the lock screen (CTRL + ALT + L) uses only a single monitor and disables the other (as in the second image). Is there a way to change that? ***I want the lock screen to extend to both monitors***, if possible.

My OS is Ubuntu 12.04. Video card is "NVIDIA Corporation G98 [GeForce 8400 GS] (rev a1)", and System Settings tab "Details" shows "Driver" as "unknown".

#### Login screen using multi monitor mode:

[image]

#### Lock screen using only a single monitor:

[image]

Comment: What? This hasn't got **anything** to do with multiple moniters. It's about costimsing the lock/login screen.

Comment: ...to work with multiple monitors. Clearly 100% unrelated.

Comment: Where does it say that?

Comment: Related and relevant info from Canonical: http://design.canonical.com/2011/12/improving-the-multi-monitor-experience-in-ubuntu/#comment-22912

Comment: @nerof61: In the title. In the first word, actually. The one that says "multimonitor".

Comment: Ok... yep. That's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the screen locks, it really has no reason to display on both screens although I can see why you would want the second screen to display something. The lock screen function and login screen are programmed separately, so they will behave differently. The only thing you can do is go to Launchpad.net and find Ubuntu. Then, report this as a bug/idea. Canonical is great about considering suggestions. Include a link in the report to this page so they can see your pictures.